# US French Dual National inquiries about immigrating to UK in wake of events

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm a dual American French citizen and I'm trying to move from America to the UK, and I have several inquiries regarding what I can and cannot do, with all of the Brexit stuff happening.

We're assuming I'm entering as a French citizen.

1. I don't believe I need a visa, for how long is this going to remain true?
2. How is the UK dealing with EU citizens? Am I going to eventually get thrown out? Is there a date I need to move by?
3. Am I allowed to work? Is there any legal restrictions from me accepting a job offer the day after I move in?
4. Am I covered under the NHS health insurance? Is there a premium? Will I eventually not be covered?
5. Will I have access to federally subsided loans for university?
6. Is there any legal restrictions on me, for example, living in an apartment? Am I allowed to enter into a contract with a landlord?
7. I could not find a way to contact the British government with these questions. The local embassy does not take inquiries. Is there any way I can get these questions answered in writing from the government?

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct.  You do not need a visa.  This will remain true as long as the UK continues to participate in the freedom of movement regime, which is at least until it formally leaves the EU.  If you arrive before then, you will be eligible to apply for "settled status" to remain in the UK.  See [Settled and pre-settled status for EU citizens and their families](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/applying-for-settled-status) for the current state of affairs; it is subject to change.
2. The UK's treatment of EU citizens is uncertain.  You could eventually be thrown out, but it is unlikely, at least in theory.  The current deadline to move in appears to be 30 June 2021, but it may be safer to move before 29 March 2019.
3. You are allowed to work. If you move in before 29 March 2019, you can accept a job offer the same day.  Whether that is the case after 29 March 2019 is less clear.
4. Everyone who works in the UK is covered by the NHS.  Some immigrants have to pay a health surcharge, but EU citizens do not.
5. I don't know anything about funding for higher education in the UK, I'm afraid, but whatever it is it will not be called "federal" because there is no federal government.
6. You can live in any apartment and enter into any contract provided you are over 18 years old.
7. Don't bother.  Whatever information you can find will be expensive as the immigration services [charge for such advice](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/uk-visa-tourists-charges-fees-email-overseas-cost-home-office-sitel-uk-a7763776.html) and [do not offer useful information beyond what's in their web pages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48488/19400).  Instead, look for what you can find at https://www.gov.uk.  You can also read up on EU freedom of movement at

   - [Free movement - EU nationals](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457&langId=en)
   - [Freedom of movement and of residence](https://ec.europa.eu/info/aid-development-cooperation-fundamental-rights/your-rights-eu/know-your-rights/citizens-rights/freedom-movement-and-residence_en)
   - [The directive itself](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616)

Answer (score 1):

phoog has address most of the questions, so I will only address 5. (I'm unable to comment due to lack of reputation here)

**Summary**: At this stage, before the UK leaves the EU, EU nationals are likely to have access to tuition fee loan (but not maintenance loans) for undergraduate degrees, and access to a combined tuition & maintenance loan to *help towards* their postgraduate degrees.

No one knows what will happen when the UK leaves the EU yet, though on the [student finance calculator](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance-calculator) the Government slapped a quote there:

> There will be no change to the rights and status of EU citizens living in the UK until 2021. You and your family can apply for ‘settled status’ to continue living in the UK after June 2021. The scheme will open fully by March 2019.

### **Undergraduate Courses**

[This GOV.UK page](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance/eu-students) covers the details related to undergraduate course fees & finance options. It has a link to [this page](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance-calculator) that shows what finance options are available for EU students.

Playing with the calculator with the following options:

- When does your course start?  Between September 2018 and August 2019
- What type of student are you? EU student full-time
- How much are your tuition fees per year?  £9,250

yields the following answer:

> Your result is an estimate. Usually, you only get student finance if you’re doing your first higher education qualification - [check if you qualify](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance/who-qualifies).
>
> **Tuition costs**
>
> You could get a [Tuition Fee Loan](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance/eu-students) - £9,250 per year.
>
> The loan pays for the cost of your course and must be paid back.
>
> **Living costs**
>
> Most EU full-time students don’t qualify for help with living costs (known as ‘maintenance’).

### **Postgraduate Courses**

[This page](https://www.gov.uk/masters-loan) and [this page](https://www.gov.uk/doctoral-loan) gives the details on Master's loan and Doctoral loan. Specifically on EU national eligibility they say:

> You may also be eligible if you’re an EU national and all the following apply:
>
> - you’re living in England on the first day of the first year of your course
> - you’ve normally lived in the European Economic Area or Switzerland for the past 3 years (this is also known as being ‘ordinarily resident’)
> - you’ll be studying at a university or college in England

Comment: Yeah, OP will probably have to pay 'international' fees as it is assessed on the basis of residence rather than nationality. If OP had been living in France then it would likely be 'home' fees, but this is not the case if they are travelling from US.

Comment: That's true - though with the numerous exceptions on such provisions, we won't know which exact case will apply to the OP.  I am also not sure if it is possible for someone to be slapped with an 'international' fee, yet sill be able to apply for a undergrad tuition loan amounting to the home fee...